# SOAPUI comment unwanted tags in request

Tags: groovy, soapui

I want to do data driven testing in SOAPUI. Hence I'm trying to feed data into scripts from an excel file. To some extent I am successful. I updated all test scripts using a groovy script.

However, there is a challenge, for some test cases I do not want to give data for a few tags.  When I leave it as empty my server throws error. Which means the tag should have a value or the tag be excluded since the tag itself is optional.

Is there a way to exclude a tag, all its children and even its parent if no other sibling has any value.

To put it another way I want enable only tags that have value or is mandatory. All other tags should be commented.

How can I achieve this using groovy script?

Example:

```
<Record>
   <Employee>
      <Name>Alfa</Name>
      <Age>28</Age>
   </Employee>
   <Location>
      <LocName></LocName>
      <State></State>
   </Location>
</Record>
```

In this code, Employee tag has information. But Location tag is not.
If I pass blank values for tags LocName and State my server will throw error. However tag Location is itself optional.
So I want my request to be like this

```
<Record>
   <Employee>
      <Name>Alfa</Name>
      <Age>28</Age>
   </Employee>
      <!--Location>
      <LocName></LocName>
      <State></State>
   </Location-->
</Record>
```

How can this be acieved?

Comment: Down vote is unfair when English is probably a second language.

Comment: Ramyaa, by Tag do you mean XML Elements or URL Parameters?

Comment: It's really had to work out what's being asked here...  Some example code would probably help

Comment: Tim, I have editied my post to be more clear on what is required. Thanks! Martin, I mean XML elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the context.expand function.

In your request you need to add your line with ${=context.expand("variable#1")!=''?'What to add':''}

Example :
DataSource#J1 and DataSource#J2 come from my datasource teststep

```
    ${=context.expand("${DataSource#J1}")!=''?'<rxas:OpeningHour>':''}
    ${=context.expand("${DataSource#J1}")!=''?'<rxas:HourFrom>'+context.expand("${DataSource#J1}")+'</rxas:HourFrom>':''}
    ${=context.expand("${DataSource#J2}")!=''?'<rxas:HourTo>'+context.expand("${DataSource#J2}")+'</rxas:HourTo>':''}
    ${=context.expand("${DataSource#J1}")!=''?'</rxas:OpeningHour>':''}
```

If your variables are empty !=' ' the value ?'example' will not be added